# moc Makefile rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, moc

Everywhere I search I keep seeing **this helpful rule**

```
moc_%.cpp: %.h
   $(MOC) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
```

It doesn't work. The Makefile goes

```
MOC:= /path/to/moc

.PHONY clean:
    rm moc_*.cpp

moc: moc_file.cpp

#moc_file.cpp: file.h # this works
#    $(MOC) $< -o $@

moc_%.cpp: %.h
    $(MOC) $< -o $@
```

The commented line, uncommented, works but the general rule doesn't. It prints out `No rule to make target 'moc_file.cpp', needed by 'moc'` Can anyone give any insight why it doesn't or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The general rule works for me. What version of Make are you using?

Comment: I have two versions, one is 3.81 and 3.82. Both do not work.

Comment: Your makefile works fine for me.  That error basically means the pattern rule doesn't apply: if, for example, file.h doesn't exist.  But you say the explicit rule works, so it must exist.  There's something else, beyond what you've posted, in your environment.  Try running "make -rd" and see if the output provides any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern rules may or may not be used by `make` depending on the weather or time of day (can you tell I don't like them?). Instead, turn them into *static pattern rules* by prefixing them with the list of targets you want them to apply to:

```
moc_file.cpp: moc_%.cpp: %.h
    $(MOC) $< -o $@
```